# Can I just create a simple website project in VS without the .NET stuff?

Tags: visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I would like to split my .NET Core web application into multiple layers:

1. UI
2. API
3. Logic/Domain
4. Data
   ...

All of them seem clear enough apart from (1). Is it possible to create a simple web site which consumes the API layer? When I mean simple I mean that I do not think it needs .NET Core, just client side libraries such as Bootstrap/Angular.

I can create a simple project like this outside of VS easily, but I want it as part of my project, when I go to New Project all I see is:

[image]

What is the correct approach to take here?

Comment: This could be a better question if you provided some focus, as evidenced by the wandering generality of the answer your question has attracted.  There is no "correct" approach.  You do whatever is most consistent with your specific goals.

Comment: You can just create a folder inside your solution folder and put all your UI files there. no `.csproj` or .NET stuff.

Comment: @Robert Harvey the question is quite specific, it just does not have a good answer. I want to know how to add a website project without .net to a VS solution.

Comment: OK, well the "project types" in Visual Studio are just helper "templates," if you will.  Nothing prevents you from assembling a project by hand, using any organizational principles you choose.